# how can i get this program : mono numeric substitution encryption ?? (a to z sub by 1 to 26)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

:this what i get tell now

```
include emu8086.inc 

DEFINE_GET_STRING


;                       'abcdefghijklmnopqrstvuwxyz'

jmp start

buffer db  "                    ",0dh,0ah,'$'
size = $ - offset buffer  ; declare constant

table2 db 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstvuwxyz'

table1 db 97 dup (' '), 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26


start:
lea     di, buffer      ; buffer offset.
mov     dx, size        ; buffer size.
call get_string
putc 0dh
putc 0ah
; encrypt:
lea bx, table1
lea bp, di
call parse

; show result:
;lea dx, di
; output of a string at ds:dP

putc 0ah
putc 0dh

; decrypt:
lea bx, table2
lea bp,di
call hamdy

; show result:
call print_string


; wait for any key...
mov ah, 0
int 16h


ret   ; exit to operating system.




; subroutine to encrypt/decrypt
; parameters: 
;             si - address of string to encrypt
;             bx - table to use.
parse proc near

osama:
    cmp [bp] , '$'    ; end of string?
    je end_of_string

    mov al, [bp]
    cmp al, 'a'
    jb  skip
    cmp al, 'z'
    ja  skip    
    ; xlat algorithm: al = ds:[bx + unsigned al] 
    xlatb     ; encrypt using table2.  
    mov [bp], al
    mov ah,0
    call print_num_uns
skip:
    inc bp
    jmp osama

end_of_string:


ret
parse endp


hamdy proc near

osama_1:
    cmp [bp] , '$'    ; end of string?
    je end_of_string_1

    mov al, [bp]
    cmp al, 1
    jb  skip_1
    cmp al, 26 
    ja  skip_1  
    ; xlat algorithm: al = ds:[bx + unsigned al] 
    xlatb     ; encrypt using table2.  
    mov [bp], al
    mov ah,0
skip_1:
    inc bp
    jmp osama_1

end_of_string_1:


ret
hamdy endp

DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS
DEFINE_PRINT_STRING
end
```

Comment: This question could be improved by explaining what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

a. I would be surprised if the call to GET_STRING would always be succesful.

```
lea     di, buffer      ; buffer offset.
mov     dx, size        ; buffer size.
call get_string
```

I guess size should NOT include the terminating carriage return, linefeed, and dollar character. I suggest you code:

```
size = ($-3) - offset buffer  ; declare constant
```

b. Your TABLE2 needs to start with an additional byte!

```
table2 db 0,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstvuwxyz'
```

or alternatively you could decrement AL before doing the translation.

```
dec al
xlatb     ; encrypt using table2
```

c. Similarly you can eliminate the use of those 97 spaces in the definition of TABLE1 by coding :

```
mov al, [bp]
cmp al, 'a'
jb  skip
cmp al, 'z'
ja  skip    
; xlat algorithm: al = ds:[bx + unsigned al] 
sub al,'a'
xlatb     ; encrypt using table1.  
mov [bp], al
```

d. The comments to your PARSE routine are wrong.

```
;             si - address of string to encrypt     --> Is bp
```

and

```
xlatb     ; encrypt using table2                    --> Is table1
```

Answer (score 0):

1)before call print_num_uns there's a missing line as print_num_uns prints from si register so u need

to lea si,di first

lea si,di

call print_num_uns

2)you need to put some character (a space,zero or anything) before the abc's in table2 because in table1,1 is indexed 98 but 'a' is indexed 97 by default so it need to have some entry in the array before it